# Translation in x & y

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How can I find the translations in the x & y coordinates in order to align edge detected images.
I have 3 edge detected images and I want to align the second and third parts(G&R) to the first(B).

How can I do this using the 'circshift' function. As I want to Use the sum of squared difference metric to measure how well images match:

Sum of squared differences: sum( (image1-image2).^2 )

I want to record the displacements in x&y that were used to align the parts for each image

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation

Answer (score 0):

The image processing toolbox has an [imregister](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/imregister.html) function that should produce some decent registrations without entering into too much detail.